# Combine three different Conditions in a single query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables. 
Condition for query :

```
Need to get number of Source_Id   with status_id=1

Need to get number of Source_Id with status_id=3 except status_id=1

Need to get number of Source_Id with status_id=2 except status_id=1 and 3
```

Table 1: status

```
  **Satus_Id    Status**
    1          Matching
    2          Not Matching
    3          Manual Matching
```

Table 2 :    Source details

```
 **Source_Id     Name   Date**
    1           Name1   21-01-2013
    2           Name2   22-01-2013
    3           Name3   22-01-2013
    4           Name4   23-02-2013
```

Table 3:  source

```
 **Id   Source_Id   Satus_Id**
    1        1            1
    2        1            2
    3        1            3
    4        2            2
    5        2            3
    6        3            3
    7        4            2
```

Expected output as

```
     **Status               Count**
   Matching                 1
   Manual Matching          2
   Not Matching         1
```

Comment: I have got the result with three different queries..

Comment: Union the three queries.

Comment: Sorry what i meant is,got result for Matching in one query,Not Matching in another query and Manual Matching yet another query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ALLCOLUMNSYOUWANTTOUSE
FROM TABLE YOU WANT
WHERE FIRST
UNION
SELECT SAMECOLMNS
FROM TABLE
WHERE SECOND
UNION
SELECT SAMECOLUMNS
FROM TABLE
WHERE THIRD
```

key to this is to use the same columns in each.

If that does not work, show the queries and tables and we can probably do a join for you